# Powershell host.ui.prompt doesn't pop up a dialog box when run from the command line

Tags: user-interface, powershell, prompt

This is a follow-up to my [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8184167/powershell-user-input-what-type-does-host-ui-prompt-return)

I have written a script which uses `$host.ui.prompt`.
The script runs fine when I run it from my editor ([PowerGUI](http://powergui.org)), and the dialog box pops up nicely to prompt the user for input, like this:

[image: dialog box appears as expected].

However, when I run it from a command line (`powershell .\script.ps1`), no dialog box pops up: instead, command line prompts appear, like this:

[image: DOS box text prompts]

I expected that the script would pop up the nice dialog box for me as before.

**What am I missing?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `$host.ui.prompt` like the name says, is specific to the host implementation. PowerGui have impemented a custom host / prompt which is GUI based. The default prompt on the console is the text one that you see.

Maybe you want to look here: http://www.windowsitpro.com/blog/powershell-with-a-purpose-blog-36/scripting-languages/getting-input-and-inputboxes-in-powershell-137449

and here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730941.aspx