# Host.ui.prompt doesn't pop up a dialog/form when run from the ISE

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

**Note:** This question is about the behavior of `$host.ui.Prompt` when run from **the ISE**. Unlike [Powershell host.ui.prompt doesn't pop up a dialog box when run from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8272138) which is about the behavior from **the command-line**. In particular, it's trying to ask why the ISE's host ui implementation does not throw a dialog for `Prompt` (although it *does* for `PromptForChoice`).

I have a simple PowerShell script that uses both `$host.ui.Prompt` and `$host.ui.PromptForChoice`.  When I run it from the ISE, `PromptForChoice` pops up a dialog but `Prompt` prompts at the console.

Read-Host also prompts at the console and does not show a dialog.

I.e.
the script below shows a dialog for the initial choice, then prompts at the console pane for both A and B. Is this normal? My reading of the documentation suggests all three should throw a dialog. Have I missed something?

I'm running PowerShell 3.0 in case that's relevant.

```
$choicedesc = New-Object System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription] 
$choicedesc.Add((New-Object "System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription" -ArgumentList "&Foo"))
$choicedesc.Add((New-Object "System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription" -ArgumentList "&Bar"))
$choice = $Host.ui.PromptForChoice("Choice", "Make a choice", $choicedesc, -1)


$a = Read-Host "A"

$fields = New-Object "System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Management.Automation.Host.FieldDescription]" 
$f = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.FieldDescription "B"
$f.DefaultValue = ""
$f.Label = "&B"
$fields.Add($f)

$result = $Host.ui.Prompt('cap','msg', $fields)
```

Comment: Which documentation are you reading? The MSDN doc for System.Management.Automation.Host.PSHostUserInterface shows that Prompt is an abstract method. It is up to the powershell host (ISE in this case) to implement it. The doc doesn't seem to me to have any guidelines on UI style. Using Reflector I see that the implementation is here: `Microsoft.Windows.PowerShell.Gui.Internal.GPSHostUserInterface.Prompt`. It is more complicated than I expected and there appears to be logic to select GUI or not. You might want to take a look at it.

Comment: I'm sure I'd seen it mentioned in the documentation, but maybe not...
However, the documentation _does_ allow for a title. Also I've seen references to `PromptForChoice` showing a window (e.g. http://powershell.org/wp/forums/topic/host-ui-promptforchoice-console-gui-box/)

Comment: That link is pretty consistent with my comment - it's up to the host to implement the method. BTW, did you take a look at the method I referenced?

Comment: Just looked at it now and I think it's broken (in my version). It calls `PromptInDialogOrOutput`, which shows a dialogue ... `if (CommandImplementation.NoGUI` ... I think this should be negated -- it's certainly inconsistent with other uses of `CommandImplementation.NoGUI`