# Expect and Spawn with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, command-line-interface, expect

Is there any way to do expect and spawn with powershell.
I have to parse a CLI program with powershell which is asking for password is there any way to input this password via powershell.
In perl or python even in bash you can use expect/spawn
Is there any solution in powershell ?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to create a text file with the encrypted password one time, then call this file as the password in as many scripts as necessary.

Create the password file once:

```
$pwd = Read-Host 'Enter password for encrypting:' -AsSecureString | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Out-File -Path 'C:\SpecialFiles\CLIPassword.txt'
```

Then you can use it whenever it's needed:

```
$pass = (Get-Content -Path 'C:\SpecialFiles\CLIPassword.txt' | ConvertTo-SecureString)
$creds = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList (<insert CLI UserName>, $pass)
```

Then when you need to supply the username and password to your script, you simply pipe

```
$creds | <command>
```

or if the command supports the -Credential parameter

```
<command> -Credential $creds
```

If your command needs the user name and password entered separately, you can do that by specifying the property name:

```
<command> -UserName $creds.UserName -Password $creds.Password
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Read-Host to prompt the user for input. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8184167/how-to-prompt-for-input-in-powershell) for more information.

```
$pass = Read-Host 'What is your password?' -AsSecureString
$decodedpass = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pass))
```

I'm sure what you want to do with spawn, but you can execute other scripts or executables by just calling them

```
.\MyOtherScript.ps1
```

Comment: Hi,
I don´t know if I don´t explain the situation clearly, I want avoid the user interaction. The program which powershell calls is asking me for the password and I want avoid this step, usually Linux to this situation I use Expect and Spawn to send keystrokes to the nested program.