# Masked user input via VB assembly called in Powershell

Tags: vb.net, powershell

I have a powershell script that would like user to enter password. It calls a function to get a pop up box for the user input. Now it is in plaintext. I'd like it to be hidden/masked

This is the function created :---

```
function Read-InputBoxDialog([string]$Message, [string]$WindowTitle, [string]$DefaultText)
{
    Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic
    return [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox($Message, $WindowTitle, $DefaultText)
}
```

This is the way i called the function from powershell : ---

```
$SQLPassword = Read-InputBoxDialog -Message "Please enter SQL password used to connect to Database Server" -WindowTitle "Sql Server Authentication" -DefaultText ""
```

How do I ask mask the password as **** ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prompt for user input In PowerShell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8184167/prompt-for-user-input-in-powershell)

Comment: This can't be done with an input box: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa164894

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of an input box, Powershell has got its own implementation `Get-Credential`. It stores credentials as secure strings, so getting a plaintext password requires some tweaking. Like so,

```
$cred = Get-Credential -Message "Enter Sql password"
$cred.GetNetworkCredential().username # Show the username
$cred.GetNetworkCredential().password # Show the password
```