# How do i make powershell custom input boxes?

Tags: powershell, textbox, inputbox

So i have this powershell...

```
pushd "C:\PSF\Move to V6\DTT Files"
$configFiles = Get-ChildItem . *.dtt -rec
foreach ($file in $configFiles)
{
(Get-Content $file.PSPath) |
Foreach-Object { $_ -replace "OLD", "NEW" } |
Set-Content $file.PSPath
(Get-Content $file.PSPath) |
Foreach-Object { $_ -replace "OLD2", "NEW2" } |
Set-Content $file.PSPath
(Get-Content $file.PSPath) |
Foreach-Object { $_ -replace "OLD3", "NEW3" } |
Set-Content $file.PSPath
}
```

What i am hoping to do is have it pop up with a few boxes asking what you want:
New, New2 and New3 to be specificly.

I am very new to powershell so i am clueless when it comes to doing something like that. (Or even if you can)

If it's not possible, i will accept suggestions for other things i can do in place of doing this.

Comment: Could you not just use `Read-Host` before the loops? Not a "popup" but the result is the same.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8184167/prompt-for-user-input-in-powershell

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PowerShell v3+ then I like using [`Out-GridView`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849920.aspx) for this purpose:

```
$choices = @('NEW', 'NEW2', 'NEW3')

$selection = $choices | Out-GridView -Title 'Select Replacement' -OutputMode Single
```

It's simple, effective, intuitive, and built-in.