# How do I prompt for input to script?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create PowerShell script that allows me to input the username and or group name and send it to our server for permissions.

Is there a way to prompt with just a text box of those 2 fields instead of inserting the names into the script each time?

```
$group = [ADSI]"WinNT://win2016-sfd-02/GROUP_NAME,group"
$group.Add("WinNT://win2016-sfd-02/DOMAIN/USER_NAME,user")
```

Comment: Very tempting dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8184167/prompt-for-user-input-in-powershell

Comment: If you wanted a single form with two boxes you will have to make that yourself I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Read-Host](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176935.aspx) is what you're after:

```
$Username = Read-Host "Please enter Username"
$GroupName = Read-Host "Please enter Groupname"

$group = [ADSI]"WinNT://win2016-sfd-02/$GroupName,group"
$group.Add("WinNT://win2016-sfd-02/DOMAIN/$Username,user")
```

Comment: Thanks James. That works perfectly. Is there a way to just run it with 1 click and then get the prompt text box?

Comment: http://www.sciosoft.com/blogs/post/2011/10/04/Launch-PowerShell-Script-from-Shortcut.aspx this works well